# How will liquidity be affected if I call ERC20 transfer() directly on a pair in Uniswap V2?

Tags: uniswap, uniswapv2

If I transfer() one of the paired X or Y tokens, or a completely unrelated Z token, to the address of an X/Y pair contract developed on UniswapV2, won't the liquidity of the pool change? (It seems like the K value will change.)
Is this an allowed policy? Or is there any logic implemented to prevent a simple transfer() to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you send X or Y, yes the pool will be changed:

- Some one can call `skim()` to get the excess token amounts that don't align with reserve0 and reserve1
- Some one can call `sync()` or perform a swap to sync the reserve with the current token balances

In the below definition, note that reserve0 and reserve1 are variables that may not equal the actual balance of token0 and token1, they need logic to sync with the balance.

```
    address public token0;
    address public token1;

    uint112 private reserve0;           // uses single storage slot, accessible via getReserves
    uint112 private reserve1;           // uses single storage slot, accessible via getReserves
```

[skim and sync source code](https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-core/blob/ee547b17853e71ed4e0101ccfd52e70d5acded58/contracts/UniswapV2Pair.sol#L190-L200)

If you send Z, nothing will change as each instance of UniswapPair only checks and serves the 2 relevant tokens.

What will actually happen? I guess there are a lot of bots listening at the blockchain right now for profitable events, your excess token will be simply collected by them immediately after they see you send it to the pair.